# What is the difference between sprain, dislocate and twist?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between **sprain**, **dislocate** and **twist**? 
I am reading the definitions and I am honestly completely confused.
Can anyone explain the difference in a much simpler way?

Comment: Isn't this a medical question?

Comment: You should at least tell us what definitions you've already read. Otherwise, someone might end up parroting them back to you, and no one will be better off than before.

Answer (score 1):

These all occur when a joint is overstressed.

A *twist* is generally a minor injury, involving hyperextension of muscles and tendons, and the like. A *sprain* occurs when the ligaments in a joint are injured, ranging anywhere from being overextended to being partially or completely torn. A *dislocation* occurs when bones are moved out of place, for example a shoulder being pulled out of its joint.